# Can metal desk legs cause grounding or interference issues?

Tags: interference, grounding, workstation

I'm currently designing an audio production desk/workstation.  I've got most of the thing worked out, planning to use mostly 3/4" maple plywood for the desk itself.

The legs are where my question comes from.  Is there any downside to using metal construction for the legs -- think either angle iron or 3/4" industrial looking piping?

I can't imagine there being issues, but I also know how sneaky some grounding issues can be, and if I'm going to potentially create a hum/grounding problem by using metal for the support structure, I'd come up with another option.

Note, this is for a home studio, and while I've invested in some equipment, I'm by no means a professions.

Comment: If you aren't letting the legs touch the cables and everything is properly terminated then I see no possibility of grounding problems.

Comment: If you make this an answer, I'll gladly accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't letting the legs touch the cables and everything is properly terminated then I see no possibility of grounding problems.